# integer number too large .error , what can I do

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, long-integer, mobile-development

I am doing a function that return the GCD of two long number, and when I tried this example I get this error "integer number too large" although I tried with too number less than the max of long value

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(reduction(149361408, 37822859361));
    }
    static long reduction(long a, long b){
        if(b==0) return a;
        return reduction(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: `reduction(149361408L, 37822859361L)`

Answer (score 2):

Add an "L" to the number so you indicate is a Long

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(reduction(149361408, 37822859361L));
    }
    static long reduction(long a, long b){
        if(b==0) return a;
        return reduction(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if it's a variable from the user ?

Comment: Khairou, If it's a `long`, it doesn't matter where it's come from.  Just make sure you never store it in an `int`.

Comment: if its an input from the user you can indicate that your program/function is going to receive a Long and you only pass that input to your function

Comment: *but what if it's a variable from the user*  -- if the user types it, it starts off as some characters, not a number, and not a variable.  You write code to convert it into a number (and you can choose int or long) and to assign it to a variable (and you can choose to use int or long)